# User privileges required for System.DirectoryServices

Tags: iis, impersonation, privileges, directoryservices

I'm using System.DirectoryServices to list the status of websites running on a server. Currently I'm using impersonation of an admin account for this to run but I'd prefer to have a specific user account with the bare minimum privileges.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525791%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it looks like DirectoryServices just delegates calls to IIS:// directory entries to the IIS ADSI provider. The [IIS ADSI Provider docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525929%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) state that you need to run it as a member of the local administrators group:

> When using ADSI to configure IIS,
>   ensure that the user account of the
>   person running the script is a member
>   of the administrators group or use
>   LogonAdmin to run the script under the
>   credentials of an administrator.